# Is there a way to style a html element on a link hover?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to ask if there is a way in CSS to style an element on a link hover.
What I mean is that for example on a link hover change the body background color to blue.

I tried to search but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Here is an example https://codepen.io/mishra93mohit/pen/QZRMbw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

Comment: simple example css - `a:hover { color: green; }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use "hover".

For example :

```
a: hover {
background-color:blue;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

However, I think it's best to share your code so that you can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so if the link elements preceeds or is the parent of the element whose background you want to change

**UPDATE**

If your html structure looks like this

```
<a class="my_link" href="example.html">My link</a>
<div class="my_element"></div>
```

In the above code, the `a` tag with class `my_link` proceeds the element which we want to change its background. In this type of scenario, you can use the CSS code below. Notice the `~` symbol...

Then in CSS

```
.my_link:hover ~ .my_element{
    background: red;
}
```

If your html structure looks like what i have below, where the `a` tag is the parent of the element whose background we want to change.

```
<a class="my_link" href="example.html">My link
     <div class="my_element"></div>
</a>
```

The CSS code below would do the trick. Notice the `~` symbol is omitted

```
.my_link:hover .my_element{
    background: red;
}
```